# solving the mathematical induction problem

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I have been reading the mathematical induction and attempt to solve this given problem

Prove that $$2\cdot2^1 + 3\cdot2^2 + 4\cdot2^3 + 5\cdot2^4 +\ldots+ (n+1)2^n = n2^{n+1}\;.$$

Any clues?

Comment: Should that be $n \cdot 2^{n+1}$?

Answer (score 4):

I’ll get you started. First get the induction off the ground by checking that the formula is correct when $n=1$:

$$2\cdot2^1=4=1\cdot2^{1+1}\;.$$

Now assume as your induction hypothesis that

$$2\cdot2^1+3\cdot2^2+\ldots+(n+1)2^n=n2^{n+1}\tag{1}$$

for some $n\ge 1$ and try to show that the result is true for $n+1$, i.e., that

$$2\cdot2^1+3\cdot2^2+\ldots+(n+1)2^n+(n+2)2^{n+1}=(n+1)2^{n+2}\;.\tag{2}$$

Notice that the first $n$ terms on the lefthand side of $(2)$ are identical to the lefthand side of $(1)$, so by applying the induction hypothesis $(1)$, we can conclude that

$$2\cdot2^1+3\cdot2^2+\ldots+(n+1)2^n+(n+2)2^{n+1}=n2^{n+1}+(n+2)2^{n+1}\;.\tag{3}$$

Now do a little algebraic manipulation of the righthand side of $(3)$ to show that it’s equal to the righthand side of $(2)$, and you’ll have proved that $(2)$ holds.

Comment: how would you show a little algebraic manipulation of the RHS of (3) to show that it is equal to the RHS of (2)??? i am confused by the explanation you have given until the last

Comment: @amie: Both terms of $n2^{n+1}+(n+2)2^{n+1}$ have a factor of $2^{n+1}$, so the first thing to try is factoring it out. If you do that, you get $(2n+2)2^{n+1}$. Can you see why that’s equal to the righthand side of $(2)$?

Comment: frankly no, im so lost. im so sorry

Comment: @amie: It’s just a little more factoring and one of the laws of exponents: $$(2n+2)2^{n+1}=2(n+1)2^{n+1}=(n+1)\left(2\cdot2^{n+1}\right)=(n+1)2^{n+2}\;.$$

Comment: okay i get it now. however, 2⋅2^1+3⋅2^2+4⋅2^3+5⋅^4+…+(n+1)2n=n2^n+1 is not equal to the final answer which is (n+1)2^2n+2. shouldnt it be equal to n2^n+1??? or am i misunderstanding your computation?

Comment: @amie: It appears that the real problem is that you don’t understand how mathematical induction works. There’s a concise description of it in the first part of [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/359208/12042), and my answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/312405/12042) gives you another illustration of the proof method in action.